# PhoneGap/Android App not working on 4.1

Tags: android, cordova

I was testing an app I built on a ASUS Transformer 10.1 running Android 4.1.1. The application loaded the splash screen then went blank. So I opened the Android SDK manager and installed SDK 4.1.2, Rebuilt the application and it is still not working. Shouldn't `Cordova build Android` in the CLI take care of this?

In addition, I checked the manifest to make sure the target SDKs were accurate. Which they are at `min:10` and `targerSDK:19` (4.1.2 is at 16)

Any idea why I am having trouble? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest you can change the `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` into `android:targetSdkVersion="16"` it will build in (4.1.2) level 16 of android

Of course after this you have to run `cordova build android` in your project folder before reopenning it in Eclipse :)

It worked for me, hope it will for you